# How to change AppCompatCheckBox color efficiently?

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I found a very strange behaviour in my AppCompatCheckBox, already searched a fix for it but didn't find, that's why I decided to ask here.

I was trying to change the checked AppCompatCheckBox color programatically (as my app's color scheme changes dinamically, I can't use the XML attributes to color the CheckBox), so I used this approach:

```
chkTos = (AppCompatCheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxTos);

ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{
                    new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked},
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked},
            },
            new int[]{

                    Color.DKGRAY,
                    Color.RED,
            }
    );
chkTos.setSupportButtonTintList(colorStateList);
```

it worked, the checked color is now red, but the animation is now VERY SLOW. The performance is terrible! How can I fix this?

Have you experienced anything like this? I wanted to show you it in action, will try to create a gif of it! Maybe this is a bug on the support library?

Some references:

[Change Circle color of radio button- Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120199/change-circle-color-of-radio-button-android)

[How to change checkbox checked color programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340256/how-to-change-checkbox-checked-color-programmatically)

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with this bug, instead of setting the `SupportButtonTintList` you have to set the `ButtonTintList` with the `colorStateList` you want. So the code will be like:

`chkTos.setButtonTintList(colorStateList);`