# Set background color of unchecked checkbox Android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-checkbox

It has to be like this:

[image]

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

**The rounded rectangle is not that important.** But the unchecked state has to be black. This is my code:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:buttonTint="@color/orange"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

This is the theme I'm using:

```
  "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

I've tried this as well:

```
<style name="checkbox_style" parent="Bijenkorf">
    <item name="material_grey_600">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Because the default unchecked has the color **#757575**. And I looked this up in the Theme and it was "material_grey_600". But this doesn't compile. Any ideas?

Comment: you can follow one of my answer on here. u require 3 xml, one for custom checkbox, 1 for when check box is checked and 1 for when checkbox is unchecked, here you define your color for black. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42764334/4056108

Comment: @Jim Clermonts try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40016892/3117966)

Comment: Follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854047/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-checkbox

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Do it like this-

**In your layout file-**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:theme="@style/CheckboxStyle"/>
```

**and in your style.xml file**

```
<style name="CheckboxStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Or you can change both the **checked and unchecked color** like this-

```
<style name="CheckboxStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>  // for checked 
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item>  // for unchecked
</style>
```

change **colorAccent and colorSecondary** with your required colors.

hope it will help you..

Comment: happy to help you.. :)

Answer (score 20):

I know it is answered but someone may find this useful, another way to achieve this is by using color state list, declare a color state list for the checkbox in an xml file

checkbox_state_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:color="@color/orange" android:state_checked="true"/>
   <item android:color="@color/black" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Now use this state list as

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:buttonTint="@color/checkbox_state_list"/>
```

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me, but this worked perfectly

Comment: Accepted answer literally didnt worked for me but this answer worked like magic +1 for this

Answer (score 2):

You have to use CheckBox style  like this:

in xml style

```
 <style name="MyCheckBox" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
 </style>
```

in xml layout
       .

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/MyCheckBox"
    ...
```