# How to apply tint to checkbox preference programmatically in Android?

Tags: android

How to apply tint to CheckBox preference programmatically in Android?

CheckBox preference is already shown with grey because of the theme but I need to apply/change tint programmatically to some other colour. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

[Tinting Checkbox on pre v21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532045/tinting-checkbox-on-pre-v21)

A checkbox can be tinted by using the theme atttribute and setting the colorControlNormal and colorControlActivated:

styles.xml

```
<style name="MyCheckBox" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">  
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/indigo</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/pink</item>
</style>
```

layout xml:

```
<CheckBox  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Check Box"
        android:theme="@style/MyCheckBox"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest @ywwynm answer from 
[How to change checkbox checked color programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40016892/8840043)

```
public static void setCheckBoxColor(AppCompatCheckBox checkBox, int uncheckedColor, int checkedColor) {
    ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
            new int[][] {
                    new int[] { -android.R.attr.state_checked }, // unchecked
                    new int[] {  android.R.attr.state_checked }  // checked
            },
            new int[] {
                    uncheckedColor,
                    checkedColor
            }
    );
    checkBox.setSupportButtonTintList(colorStateList);
}
```

setting `setSupportButtonTintList` with `ColorStateList` then setting checked and unchecked state programmatically will surely reach your answer